# MongoDB - Same _id in different collections

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections called `Users` and `ElectedUsers`. `ElectedUsers` is a subset of `Users`.

The main reason to have two collection is there are some unique different services for each collection. So I have to maintain two collections for that.

But when saving documents to `ElectedUsers` first it fetch the document from `Users` collections and do some business logic and save it to `ElectedUsers` with same `_id`. For the particular document `_id` field in both collections can be same.

I want to know is it violating best practices ? or is it impact to sharding or any other operation badly ?

Comment: No, it is ok to do this so long as it is designed to and you take care of it in your programming

Comment: Plus, I assume that the schema design is a bit strange. Since it's perfectly fine to have documents with different sets of fields in one collection, I do not see the point in putting a subset in a different collection.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg the reason to have two collection is its contextualized and have some different business logic implemented with it. Yes agreed we can have different attributes in same collection but because of the contextualization and the unique business logic that attach services I thought it will better to have two collections.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using _id as the shard key, then having duplicate _id values can be problematic, otherwise if you are not using _id as shard key and maintaining some other global unique value for sharding, then there shouldn't be any issue

refer this link

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/sharding/

Comment: How cna it be problematic for sharding? That link doesn't really say

Comment: @user3266530: Since shard keys are based on collections and `_id`s need to be unique only per collection, I do not see the point.

Comment: provided link doesn't say anything about `_id` and collection sharding

Comment: check this, this is the issue that one can face with duplicate _ids https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/4e9737IbmbM

Comment: That is two objects in the SAME collection with the SAME _id